# how to convert SQL query to MongoDB query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need a help of you guys to convert a SQL query to mongodb query.

This is my query:
`SELECT secret FROM users WHERE email = ?`

Comment: have you tried reading documentation first or even: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-comparison/ ?

Comment: not a proper question

Answer (score 2):

In mongodb if you want to select data use `db.collection.find()` then if you want select data with where value with your query you can add condition value in `()` with `({ email : ? })`

replace collection with name of table, because in mongodb table = collection